# How do you GRANT SELECT on hidden resource database mssqlsystemresource?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I get an error when I run this query:

```
    SELECT 
      dependencies.referencing_id as object_id,
      dependencies.referencing_minor_id as column_id,
      dependencies.referenced_id AS referenced_object_id,
      RTRIM(referenced_objects.type) AS referenced_type
    FROM 
      sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS dependencies
    JOIN sys.objects AS referenced_objects WITH(NOLOCK) ON referenced_objects.object_id = dependencies.referenced_id
    WHERE dependencies.referencing_id != dependencies.referenced_id
```

**Error**:

*The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sql_expression_dependencies', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.*

The Login has membership only in the PUBLIC server role and granted VIEW ANY DATABASE and VIEW ANY DEFINITION.  I added a User with membership in the PUBLIC database role for the database I am comparing.  I assumed the server level permission would suffice, but I was wrong. I did this on a 2008R2 database in addition to a 2014 database.

On the 2014 database I also granted server level permission SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES.  The error persisted.

I granted the User SELECT on the database.  The error persisted.

I removed the SELECT permission and added the User to the data_reader database role.  The query resolved, however no data is returned (running the same query as a sysadmin returns 130+ rows).  Now I'm completely baffled.

I granted SELECT to the user on sys.sql_expression_dependencies  explicitly with the same results above.

After researching these permissions, the consensus seems to be that granting SELECT to a User on a database is the same as adding the User to the data_reader role.  But this is obviously not the case.  I want to create a Login/User with the smallest privilege set possible to achieve the comparison.

How do I grant access to the sys.sql_expression_dependencies view in mssqlsystemresource without granting data_reader access on the whole DB? Is there a way to grant SELECT on mssqlsystemresource only?

**Note - I've read a couple of other posts on SE regarding mssqlsystemresource but they don't pertain to this:

- I have no DENY anything assigned to this Login/User
- Membership in the PUBLIC role (server or database) has no bearing since the permissions are identical to those on a "known good" server.
- I'd rather not have the user have blanket SELECT permissions on the entire database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure where you've stumbled along the way, but this works for me:

```
CREATE LOGIN permtest WITH PASSWORD = 'x', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
USE somedatabase;
GO
CREATE USER permtest FROM LOGIN permtest;
GO
```

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx), the user needs `SELECT` permission on `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`, and `VIEW DEFINITION` on the database.

In my experimentation, the following allowed the user to select from the view, but it returned 0 rows, because they don't have the ability to view definition (which includes dependency chains):

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.sql_expression_dependencies TO permtest;
```

In order to actually see any relationships in `somedatabase`, I also had to add the following:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::floob TO permtest;
```

I could not find any way to make that more granular (`VIEW`/`DENY` definition worked for individual objects, but without the database-level right, I still couldn't see any rows in the catalog view, and `DENY` did not prevent the objects from showing up in the catalog view nor did it even prevent me from viewing the definition). I feel like SQL Server would have a hard time resolving that granularity anyway - if you had a view that referenced a table, how should the catalog view look if you have grant on the view and deny on the table, or vice versa?

If you don't want to grant `VIEW DEFINITION` on the database, then create procedures that use `EXECUTE AS OWNER`, select (filtered?) rows from the catalog view, and give the users (and of course, that could also be a role) execute permissions on the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetDependencies
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT is_schema_bound_reference --, ...
    FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies;
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.GetDependencies TO permtest;
```

Comment: I walked through your answer and it worked as expected!  I think I stumbled on the VIEW DEFINITION.  I set it for the user at the instance level instead of the database level, assuming instance would filter down.  Thank you sir!