# cannot INSERT data from wsl to SQL SERVER on Window host

Tags: sql-server, python

My problem is about cannot insert new data even I granted the insert function on SMSS. Specifically, My Python app is running in WSL environment, and the SQL Server installed on Window host. The app receives input from user and directly insert data into SQL Server by using

```
df.to_sql("userFeedback", con = engine, if_exists = 'append', dtype={'User': NVARCHAR,                                                               
                 'Feedback': NVARCHAR})
```

I gave the permission of all INSERT, REPLACE, DELETE, ... for the app but it still sends an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'userFeedback', database 'rap_platform', schema 'dbo'. (229) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [userFeedback] ([index], timestamp, datetime, [User], [Feedback]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (0, 1684236209, '2023-05-16 18:23:29', 'sfasfd', 'asfdf')]
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: see - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210254/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-configurations-database-mssql